# Uploading file revisions with Dropbox Core API in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am having a lot of trouble syncing file revisions to dropbox with the "withParentRev" parameter in "uploadFile."

Basically, I export information to a .pdf file. I want to upload the .pdf to dropbox, and if it's a new file it should upload it with "withParentRev=nil," but if the file exists then it should get the revisions. I have tried using loadMetadata on the file, but because the dropbox calls are synchronous I am having trouble uploading the right files.

No one else seems to have good sample code on how to do and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/204335035-Uploading-file-revisions-with-iOS-Core-API ]